# Redirect whole site from http to https except one route with query parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have read some question about redirect the whole site from http to https changing .htaccess like this:

```
  # Rewrite http://www.example.com to https://www.example.com
  #
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

It works good, but I need to exclude one route from this redirect, and I have found examples for a static url, but I haven't found a rule (RewriteCond) when the url has query parameters. I want that a custom route was accessed only with http. This route requires some query parameters that must be present, and other are optionals. For exmple:

```
http://<mydomain>/dataregister?device=id1234&val1=20&val2=30&hash=12345689
```

I think I should add another RewriteCond to exclude this route, but I'm not sure how to do it. I have tried with this, but It doesn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} != /dataregister [NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have it like this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/dataregister/?\? [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Pattern `/dataregister/?\?` will match original URL that contains either `/dataregister/?` or `/dataregister\?`.

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing change.

Comment: @briast: Did this work out?

Comment: I haven't tested it yet. As soon as I get to work I'll check it.

Comment: I have tested it, but It doesn't work. I need all routes to https, but a custom route, with query parameters, to http. I have cleared the browser cache and I have tested it with different browser.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide full .htaccess. Also provide the URL you are using to test these rules.